# Crash when opening a view controller with a KDCircularProgress "return mod ..."

Tags: swift, uitableview, modulo, kdcircularprogress

Everytime I re-open the app, my UITableView which contains a KDCircularProgress in every cell crashes with this error. Any idea how to fix it? (it doesn't crash all the time, sometimes it works too)

I think it's the value "value" which has a problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: First, please post your actual code, and not a screenshot. Secondly, the reason this is crashing, as your presume, is the value, which has become infinity, which really can't be accessed. You may need to set the value back to some default when the app goes to the background to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded to fix it, I was sending a NaN value for the Angle when using animateToAngle!